# Prevent RelativeLayout from wrapping around the background image

Tags: android, android-relativelayout

I have a RelativeLayout. I wanted to apply a shadow effect on it, so I defined a custom background (*updatebg.xml*):

```
    <layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

        <item android:id="@+id/background" >
            <shape android:shape="rectangle">
                <solid android:color="#449966"/>
            </shape>
        </item>

        <item android:id="@+id/shadow">
            <bitmap  android:src="@drawable/shadow" 
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"  
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"  
            />
        </item>
    </layer-list>
```

And the RelativeLayout:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:id="@+id/layoutP"
    android:background="@drawable/updatebg"
    >
</RelativeLayout>
```

Everything works great, except that the RelativeLayout gets stretched to the same height as the background image height (shadow). If I have content inside the RelativeLayout that takes less height than the height of the shadow background image, then the RelativeLayout will be stretched to "wrap around the background" as well, instead of wrapping around just the content inside RelativeLayout.

I need for the background image to ether adjust to the parents height (RelativeLayout) or get cropped off. Any hints on how to accomplish this? Thanks!

I'm trying to apply the gradient type of shadow from top to bottom:
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Edit**

Maybe I have misunderstood what you said "shadow effect", if you just want a gradient, use `<gradient>` drawable.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <item android:id="@+id/background" >
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="#449966"/>
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item>
        <shape
            android:dither="true"
            android:shape="rectangle" >
            <gradient
                android:angle="270"
                android:endColor="#7fffffff"
                android:startColor="#7f000000" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

The result is like:

[image: result]

**Original Answer**

You should consider using a `9-Patch` png instead. It's like this:

[image: 9-Patch]

It's just a normal png image but with some addition markers (the black points/lines on the borders), and Android will use these markers to stretch the image as you want.

For more details about how to use the `9-Patch` file, see [the official docs](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/draw9patch).

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I'm trying to apply a simple gradient shadow from top to bottom, the width is applying properly, only issue is the height. Seems like there should be a simple argument I'm missing. Is it possible to do this without 9-Patch PNG's? Thanks!